# Laravel Form Validation using Ajax and Bootstrap Modal issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I' got Bootstrap Modal that allow user to update his password :

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="settingModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
            </div>
            {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/users/updatePassword', 'method' => 'POST', 'id'=>'passUpdate')) !!}
            <div class="modal-body">
                @if(Session::has('error'))
                    <div class="alert-box success">
                        <h2>{{ Session::get('error') }}</h2>
                    </div>
                @endif

                <div id="password-group" class="form-group has-feedback @if ($errors->has('password')) has-error @endif">
                    {!! Form::password('password', array('id'=>'password', 'class' => 'text input form-control', 'placeholder'=>'New Password')) !!}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback @if ($errors->has('password')) has-error @endif"></span>
                    @if ($errors->has('password')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</p> @endif
                    <div id ="password_error"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="password_confirmation-group" class="form-group has-feedback @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation')) has-error @endif">
                    {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', array('id'=>'password_confirmation', 'class' => 'text input form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Confirm New Password')) !!}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation')) has-error @endif"></span>
                    @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</p> @endif
                    <div id ="password_confirm_error"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
                <button type="button" class=" pull-left btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                {!! Form::submit('Submit', array('class'=>' pull-right btn btn-primary btn-flat'))!!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::close()!!}

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

This my JS code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#passUpdate').submit(function(e){
    var $form = $(this);

    e.preventDefault(); //keeps the form from behaving like a normal (non-ajax) html form
    var url = $form.attr('action');
    var formData = {};
    //submit a POST request with the form data
    $form.find(':input').each(function()
    {
        formData[ $(this).attr('name') ] = $(this).val();
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
    console.log('Before Submit');
    //submits an array of key-value pairs to the form's action URL
    $.post(url, formData, function(response) {
        //handle successful validation
        console.log("Success");
    }).fail(function(response) {
        //handle failed validation
        console.log("Failed");
        associate_errors(response['errors'], $form);
    });

});

function associate_errors(errors, $form)
{
    //remove existing error classes and error messages from form groups
    $form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-errors').find('.help-text').text('');
    errors.foreach(function(value, index)
    {
        //find each form group, which is given a unique id based on the form field's name
        var $group = $form.find('#' + index + '-group');

        //add the error class and set the error text
        $group.addClass('has-errors').find('.help-text').text(value);
    }
}
```

And here's my part of my laravel Controller :

```
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        // If validation fails redirect back to login.
        return Response::json(array(
            'fail' => true,
            'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
        ));
    }
```

So I got this issue :

- In firebug console I get : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list } : in last line of JS code
- Also my JS function **$('#passUpdate').submit** is never called.

**NB** Laravel is returning a JSON response correctly.

**Update** I've fixed the the first part of issue, now my form is submitted and JSON Response is recived but the form Validation doesn't work, the error are not shown on the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `)` of the `foreach`:

```
function associate_errors(errors, $form) {
    //remove existing error classes and error messages from form groups
    $form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-errors').find('.help-text').text('');
    errors.foreach(function (value, index) {
        //find each form group, which is given a unique id based on the form field's name
        var $group = $form.find('#' + index + '-group');

        //add the error class and set the error text
        $group.addClass('has-errors').find('.help-text').text(value);
    });
}
```

Note the second last line above.

> });

Comment: Yeah thank's, this solved first part, but It's still printing the JSON response in blank page instead of showing error in the Modal

Comment: Is `submit()` called?

Comment: Yeah is called **I'm here is printed** also I have added the **e** like this function(**e**)

Comment: Try printing `response` in the `post` success callback

Comment: Console.log in the fail and success block is not printed

Comment: Yeah in the network tab the json response is recived but it's not displayed on the form

Comment: because you haven't done anything with response in the `post` first callback. Add your logic here.